# How to junit List<Map<String, String>> in java?

Tags: java, junit, assert

I am trying to jUnit one of my method which returns List of Map.

```
List<Map<String, String>> mappings = TestUtils.getMappings(maps, debug);

System.out.println(mappings);
```

Below is the ouput I am getting -

```
[{dc1=h1, dc2=h2, dc3=h3}, 
{dc1=h4, dc2=h5, dc3=h6}, 
{dc1=h7, dc2=h8, dc3=h9}, 
{dc1=h10, dc2=h11, dc3=h1}, I am trying to jUnit one of my method which returns `List of Map<String, String>` - 

List<Map<String, String>> mappings = TestUtils.getMappings(maps, debug);

System.out.println(mappings);
```

Below is the ouput I am getting -

```
[{dc1=h1, dc2=h2, dc3=h3}, 
{dc1=h4, dc2=h5, dc3=h6}, 
{dc1=h7, dc2=h8, dc3=h9}, 
{dc1=h10, dc2=h11, dc3=h1}, 
{dc1=h2, dc2=h1, dc3=h4}, 
{dc1=h5, dc2=h4, dc3=h7}, 
{dc1=h8, dc2=h7, dc3=h10}, 
{dc1=h11, dc2=h10, dc3=h2}, 
{dc1=h3, dc2=h6, dc3=h8}, 
{dc1=h9, dc2=h3, dc3=h5}, 
{dc1=h6, dc2=h9, dc3=h11}]
```

I am trying to to see whether each Map has correct values or not.. In short each Map will have values like this -

`dc1=h9, dc2=h3, dc3=h5`

So I need to junit, that value of `dc1`, `dc2` and `dc3` are different than each other in the same map.

So if the map is like this -

`dc1=h1, dc2=h2, dc3=h1`

Then my assertion should fail as value of dc1 is there in dc3 as well..

Now I am not sure what is the best to jUnit this?
    {dc1=h2, dc2=h1, dc3=h4}, 
    {dc1=h5, dc2=h4, dc3=h7}, 
    {dc1=h8, dc2=h7, dc3=h10}, 
    {dc1=h11, dc2=h10, dc3=h2}, 
    {dc1=h3, dc2=h6, dc3=h8}, 
    {dc1=h9, dc2=h3, dc3=h5}, 
    {dc1=h6, dc2=h9, dc3=h11}]

Now I am not sure what is the best to jUnit this? Actually I am facing problem in doing jUnit for a Map

I am trying to to see whether each Map has correct values or not.. In short each Map will have values like this -

`dc1=h9, dc2=h3, dc3=h5`

So I need to junit, that value of `dc1`, `dc2` and `dc3` are different than each other in the map.

So if the map is like this -

`dc1=h1, dc2=h2, dc3=h1`

Then my assertion should fail as value of dc1 is there in dc3 as well..

**UPDATE:-**

For some other input, I would see output like this -

```
[{dc1=h1, dc2=h2, dc3=h3},
 {dc1=h2, dc2=h1},
 {dc1=h3, dc2=h4, dc3=h2},
 {dc2=h5, dc3=h1},
 {dc2=h3},
 {dc2=h6},
 {dc2=h7},
 {dc2=h8},
 {dc2=h9},
 {dc2=h10},
 {dc2=h11}]
```

Comment: What is it you are trying to test? Don't use junit as a verb.

Comment: Just updated the question.. Sorry I was too early in posting the question.. I forgot to add few things..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a List of Maps. Each Map has N keys, and you state you want to make sure there are no duplicate values in each map.

1) get the values for each Map
2) instantiate a HashSet and add the values
3) verify the length of the set is N

Comment: Good logic..This works fine if I have dc1, dc2, dc3 coming in the output.. But for some other inputs, I would see only dc1, dc2 in the Map.. I have updated my question with another outputs.

Comment: Then obviously you'd need to **record the initial number of values** in the map, and compare it with the resulting number in the hashset. Edited to replace `3` with `N`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

Verifies all values are unique:

```
    for(Map<String, String> eachMap : mapList) {
        Collection<String> values = eachMap.values();
        Set<String> valuesAsSet = new HashSet<>(values);
        assertEquals(values.size(), valuesAsSet.size());

    }
```

If you need to verify order:

```
    for(Map<String, String> eachMap : mapList) {
        Collection<String> values = eachMap.values();
        Set<String> valuesAsSet = new HashSet<>(values);

        Iterator<String> expectedIt = values.iterator();
        Iterator<String> actualIt = valuesAsSet.iterator();

        boolean expectedHasNext = expectedIt.hasNext();
        boolean actualHasNext = actualIt.hasNext();

        // Iterators are consistent
        assertEquals(expectedHasNext, actualHasNext);
        if(expectedHasNext) {
            if(expectedHasNext) {
                String expected = expectedIt.next();
                String actual = actualIt.next();
                assertEquals(expected, actual);
            }
        }
    }
```